# doctrine 2 no metadata classes to process

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I already integrated zf 1 with doctrine 2

I created entities by this:
php doctrine.php orm:convert-mapping --force --from-database annotation C:/wamp/www/ip/application/models

now I'm going to create getter and setter for them and generating entities I get the errors  no metadata classes to process

php doctrine.php orm:generate-entities  --generate-annotations="true" C:/wamp/www/ip/application/models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- In the entity files generated, you need to delete this line:

> > "use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;"

2- and also delete all appearances of ORM\

Comment: Yes, and maybe there is no need to do NO 1

Comment: It probably should be marked as answer than. So newcomers can quickly orientate and see it's resolved.

Comment: No it's not working. I have tried but its showing same message. "No Metadata Classes to process."