# zf2 + doctrine2 and No Metadata Classes to process

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, metadata

I'm using tutorial http://www.nuvolia.com/2013/03/09/zend_framework_doctrine_install/. The module Application fork fine with Doctrine ORM but when i'm tring to connect in another module i'm reciving error:

```
    d:\Aptana Studio\Projects\app01>vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create

Deprecated: "Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DialogHelper" is deprecated since
version 2.5 and will be removed in 3.0. Use "Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Qu
estionHelper" instead. in D:\Aptana Studio\Projects\app01\vendor\symfony\console
\Helper\DialogHelper.php on line 34
No Metadata Classes to process.

d:\Aptana Studio\Projects\app01>
```

Application I created from skeleton, Module has such code:
/app01/module/MyBlog/config/module.config.php

```
    <?php
namespace MyBlog;

return array(

        'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            'myblog_entity' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/MyBlog/Entity')
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    'MyBlog\Entity' => 'myblog_entity'
                )
            )
        ),
        'eventmanager' => array(
             'orm_default' => array(
                 'subscribers' => array(
                     'Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener',
                     // 'Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener',
                     // 'Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener',
                     // 'Gedmo\Blameable\BlameableListener',
                     // 'Gedmo\Loggable\LoggableListener',
                     // 'Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener',
                     // 'Gedmo\Sortable\SortableListener',
                     // 'Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener',
                 ),
             ),
         )
    )
);
```

/app01/module/MyBlog/src/MyBlog/Entity/BlogPost.php

```
    <?php
namespace MyBlog\Entity;

//use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

class BlogPost {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this -> id;
    }

    /**
     * Set id.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setId($id) {
        $this -> id = (int)$id;
    }

    /**
     * Get title.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle() {
        return $this -> title;
    }

    /**
     * Set title.
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this -> title = $title;
    }

}
```

/app01/module/MyBlog/Module.php

```
    <?php
namespace MyBlog;

class Module
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
                'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                        'namespaces' => array(
                                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                                //__NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . str_replace('\\', '/' , __NAMESPACE__),
                        ),
                ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

/app01/config/application.config.php

```
return array(
// This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',
    'ZendDeveloperTools',
    'MyBlog'
),
```

/app01/config/autoload/doctrine.local.php

```
    <?php
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' =>'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'user'     => 'zf2guard',
                    'password' => 'zf2guard',
                    'dbname'   => 'app01',
                    'driverOptions' => array(
                        \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'),
                )
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

What am I do wrong? Why is it work in Application module and is not work in other Module?
I try to remove ORM from my Class ([doctrine 2 no metadata classes to process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080186/doctrine-2-no-metadata-classes-to-process)) but nothing change.
Are you have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your entity does not have the `@ORM\Entity` annotation. In that case whole class is skipped by class-metadata AnnotationDriver.

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog_post")
 */
class BlogPost
{
    // ...
}
```