# Symfony 4 + Sonata + Sonata Doctrine ORM Admin Bundle: Error: No Metadata classes to process

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata

I'm trying to get Sonata working with Symfony 4 using the Sonata Doctrine ORM Admin Bundle.

I've installed the following (not sure if all of this is necessary) and added my database details to the .env file and this does show me a blank sonata admin page.

```
symfony-skeleton
sonata-project/admin-bundle
sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle
symfony/orm-pack
symfony annotations
```

Now I want to add entities to my project, so I've copied some entities from a tutorial, put them in the `src\Entity` folder and added the `namespace` and the `use as ORM` statements:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

// ...
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
// ...

class Category
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BlogPost", mappedBy="category")
    */
    private $blogPosts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->blogPosts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getBlogPosts()
    {
        return $this->blogPosts;
    }

    // ...
}
```

and

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

// ...
class BlogPost
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="body", type="text")
     */
    private $body;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="draft", type="boolean")
     */
    private $draft = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="blogPosts")
     */
    private $category;
}
```

But when I run `php bin/console doctrine:schema:create` it tells me `No Metadata classes to process.`

What am I missing?

`app\config\packages\doctrine.yaml`:

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

and `app\config\bundles.php`:

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\DatagridBundle\SonataDatagridBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

Comment: When those links eventually die, your question and the answers become useless. Put in your question exactly what you did.

Comment: Did you try clear your cache?

Comment: @Imanali Mamadiev Yes I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to my question here: [zf2 + doctrine2 and No Metadata Classes to process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557468/zf2-doctrine2-and-no-metadata-classes-to-process)

The example classes from the tutorial I was using didn't have the @Entity annotation and were therefore skipped by Doctrine.

Comment: Wow, it's crazy how much Symfony actually sucks! Had the same problem :/

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to cleaning the cache, because Doctrine is caching all data. Try this command:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

You should have this configuration inside your `app/config/config.yml` file:

```
doctrine:

    ...

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            AppBundle:
                mapping: true
                type: annotation
                alias: Blog
                prefix: App\Bundle\Entity
```

And make sure your `Sonata AdminBundle` is registered in AppKernel.

Comment: I don't have a app/config/config.xml file, the settings you mention appear to be in my app/config/packages/doctrine.yaml file, but it looks slightly different from yours, I'll update my OP with it.